# differences in jQuery keypress between Firefox and the other browsers

Tags: jquery, firefox, browser

I noticed a significant difference in behavior between Firefox and other browsers, in jquery keypress event.
This is my code, and it works, but for example if i want to select all text with "ctrl+a" i can't with firefox because it prevent the typing "a".
Also with backspace and enter the same problem.
In chrome and IE for example this keys are not considered as key typing in this type of event.

If you want to try, here is my code.

Ah the version of my jQuery is 2.2.4, i don't know if it's important.
Thank you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
console.log('ready');
$('#user_telephone').on('keypress',function(e){
    console.log(e.which);
    if (e.which!=43 && e.which!=49 && e.which!=50 && e.which!=51 && e.which!=52 && e.which!=53 && e.which!=54 && e.which!=55 && e.which!=56 && e.which!=57 && e.which!=48 && e.which!=8){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

});

```
<input id="user_telephone" type="text" class="form-control" name="user_telephone" value="" placeholder="Telephone*" required="required" />
```